# How to change the frame of a UIView subclass on device orientation which is programmatically created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, landscape-portrait

I have a `UIView` subclass which is created programmatically.

I have portrait and landscape mode in my application which uses autolayout.

Initially the `UIView` frame is set using `initWithFrame`, but when the orientation changes to landscape the `CGRect` of `UIView` is stuck with the portrait mode.

How can I alert the `UIView` subclass to change the `CGRect` on device orientation?

This is my initial frame setup code for the `UIView`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame videoUrl:(NSURL *)videoUrl{
    
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    
    if (self) {
        _frame_width = frame.size.width;
        
        int thumbWidth = ceil(frame.size.width*0.05);
        
        _bgView = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(thumbWidth-BG_VIEW_BORDERS_SIZE, 0, frame.size.width-(thumbWidth*2)+BG_VIEW_BORDERS_SIZE*2, frame.size.height)];
        _bgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        _bgView.layer.borderWidth = BG_VIEW_BORDERS_SIZE;
        [self addSubview:_bgView];
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to change the frame size of view when app changes its orientation, right ?

Comment: @vaibhav yes.I have to change the UIView CGRect.

Comment: check my ans if suits ..

Answer (score 0):

Just detect the orientation of device whether it is in `landscape` or `portrait` mode and then change the size of `UIView` accordingly see below code:

**To detect device orientation:**

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation ]== UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        UIView *view = [classObject setupView:xPos yPos:yPos width:widthValue height:heightValue];
        yourView.frame = view.frame;
        NSLog(@"device orientation Landscapse");
    }
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
    {
        UIView *view  = [classObject setupView:xPos yPos:yPos width:widthValue height:heightValue];
        yourView.frame = view.frame;
        NSLog(@"device orientation portrait");
    }
}
```

Write this method inside your class, no need to call from anywhere it will detect orientation when user rotate.

Create custom method inside your class which is returning `UIView` with complete frame and call by sending x,y position and its width and height when user changes orientation see below code:

```
-(UIView *) setupView:(float)x yPos:(float)y width:(float)width height:(float) height{

    UIView *yourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
    yourView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return yourView;
}
```

Comment: I am adding this UIView subclass as a subview to my viewcontroller where am detecting the orientation change.The problem is I have to sent a trigger to the UIView subclass to change the frame size on orientation change. Initially the UIView frame is setup for portrait only,but when it comes to landscape the frame doesn't change.I need a way out to send some trigger to the UIView's delegate method on device orientation.

Comment: is there any method you have created to set and create the view inside your class ? can you please show that class code ..

Comment: " [self.view addSubview:_videoRangeSlider];" I added it like this.I have a seperate UIView subclass where the CGRect has to be changed and a separate ViewController where the UIView is added as a subview.I need to trigger the orientation from ViewController to the UIView subclass.

Comment: @AkhilJiji above i have posted its an example just see and let me know if still have any doubt ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autoresizingMask` for both of your view and it's background view to support orientation changes. These masks will be translated to auto layout constrains automatically because `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is enabled by default e.g.:

```objectivec
@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) UIControl* bgView;

@end

@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        
        int thumbWidth = ceil(frame.size.width*0.05);
        self.bgView = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(thumbWidth-BG_VIEW_BORDERS_SIZE, 0, frame.size.width-(thumbWidth*2)+BG_VIEW_BORDERS_SIZE*2, frame.size.height)];
        self.bgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.bgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        self.bgView.layer.borderWidth = BG_VIEW_BORDERS_SIZE;
        [self addSubview:_bgView];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```